# Active Model Serializer remove relationship member when using JSON API

Tags: active-model-serializers, json-api

I'm using the latest AMS `v0.10.0.rc3` with the JSON API adapter.

So far is working great and is adding some useful conventions that i would like to change.

For example, lets suppose that i have a Post serializer and a Comment serializer like this:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Then if i request `/posts/1` for example i get the following

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "posts",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "My awesome title",
    },
    "relationships": {
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "comments"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "comments"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how the `relationships` member appears and according with the [spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) is marked as an optional member with **MAY**.
It is a nice convention that i need to override some times.

So my question is:

- How i remove the `relationship` member at the serializer or controller level ?

(If i miss some detail please comment and i will update the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your best option is to define two serializers, one with the associations, one without, and specify in your render call which to use (`render json: posts, each_serializer: PostWithoutAssociationsSerializer`).

There is an ongoing discussion about adding an `include_if` option to associations and attributes, which you could potentially leverage if it gets merged.

Comment: Note that, unless your application needs to be really highly performant, you could also simply disregard the `relationships` in the payload.

Comment: Yes, but how i actually remove the `relationships` member in the other serializer ?

Comment: Simply don't specify any association (`has_many`, `belongs_to` or `has_one`).

Comment: @beauby what if you need previously included relationship for a computed attribute but you do not want the relationship data itself? AMS  will recall the included relationship if you dont specify has_one or has_many